# Access a downloaded file programmatically

Tags: android, json

I downloaded a file with getExternalStorageDirectory(). I need to access the file so that I can parse it.
Have been looking for a way to do that for hours.

If more information is needed I'd love to provide it.

Comment: When you downloaded that file you probably did set a name and choose the directory, right? Now for reading you create a new file passing that directory and the name... Something like ```new File(getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName + "." + fileExtension);```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.
Can I use that same line for checking if the file already exists, say before the file gets downloaded?

Comment: Yes, you can use that to create the File reference, and then you call ```file.exists()```.